# From a pair to a list in lambda calculus / scheme

Tags: lambda, scheme, lisp, lambda-calculus, sicp

I'm learning a bit about lambda calculus (which is very neat) and have defined the following in scheme for how a pair would be done:

```
; PAIR
; λabf.fab
(define PAIR (lambda (a) (lambda (b) (lambda (f) ((f a) b)))))
(define mypair ((PAIR 1) 2))

; FIRST
; λab.a
(define FIRST (lambda (a) (lambda (b) a)))

; SECOND
; λab.b
(define SECOND (lambda (a) (lambda (b) b)))

(display "First is: ")     (display (mypair FIRST))
(display " | Second is: ") (display (mypair SECOND))
```

```
First is: 1 | Second is: 2
```

How would one abstract this further to create a data structure of a list, for example, to make something like `[1 2 3 4 5]` instead of just `[2 3]` ?

The best I've been able to do by myself is to sort of hardcode these, for example, for five:

```
(define five (
    (PAIR 1) (
      (PAIR 2) (
        (PAIR 3) (
          (PAIR 4) 5)))))

(display (five FIRST)) (display ((five SECOND) FIRST)) (display (((five SECOND) SECOND) FIRST)) (display ((((five SECOND) SECOND) SECOND) FIRST)) (display ((((five SECOND) SECOND) SECOND) SECOND))
```

```
12345
```

Is there a more 'general' solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normal LISP lists are not `[1 2 3]`, they are `(1 . (2 . (3 . ())))`. They are created with `(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 '())))` so the exact equal list in lambda calculus would be `((PAIR 1) ((PAIR 2) ((PAIR 3) ...)))`

Now a standard lisp implementation usually prints `(1 2 3)`, but that is some funky magic done by the printer. Its rule is that if the `cdr` is a list you can omit the dot and one set of parentheses. When you are using lambda calculus to model data the REPL will always show lambda/closure objects so you need utility functions that understands the structure and displays a visualization that corresponds. This is not par of lambda calculus as for it it is OK to just satisfy the axioms:

```
(car (cons a b)) ; ==> a
(cdr (cons a b)) ; ==> b
```

`list` is a auxiliary function that `cons` chain the arguments. You could indeed make something similar for pairs but it is not a part of lambda calculus:

```
(define TRUE (lambda (p) (lambda (q) p)))
(define NIL (lambda (x) TRUE))

(define (ch-list . args)
  (let helper ((lst (reverse args)) (result NIL))
    (if (null? lst)
        result
        (helper (cdr lst)
                ((PAIR (car lst)) result)))))
```

Comment: thanks for this great explanation. How would that compare to something like this though? https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/67555/lambda-calculus-lists-construction-explanation

Comment: @David542 `ch-list` creates the same structure as when you do it manually. How you define your lists isn't important as long as you do the same ways for all the primitives such that the contract is obeyd. Remember `ch-list` is not in lambda calculus. It is in Scheme. Its result is indistinuishable to how you would create a list in lambda calculus.

Comment: in case this might be of interest (somewhat related): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67594976/example-assembly-machine-instruction-from-lambda-calculus

Answer (score 1):

As Sylwester says. Lists are not arrays, they are chains of conses, ending in a special `nil` or `()` object.  That means that to build such things you need both `cons` and this special object.

I have a toy language implemented in Racket called 'oa' (one argument), which, as of a few minutes ago, you can find [here](https://github.com/tfeb/oa).  In its purest variant the syntax of functions is, for instance `(λ x x)`: there are no parens around the argument because why would there be?  There is `define` to give things names as well, but that's pretty much it.  Here is an implementation of conses in this language:

```
(define true (λ x (λ y x)))
(define false (λ x (λ y y)))

(define cons (λ h (λ t (λ s ((s h) t)))))
(define car (λ l (l true)))
(define cdr (λ l (l false)))
(define nil (λ l true))
(define null? (λ l (l (λ h (λ t false)))))
```

Conveniently (but also annoyingly), oa uses the normal Racket reader, so you can read numbers, even though they have no semantics in the language.  So, for instance

```
> (cdr ((cons 1) 1))
1
```

To make, say, a three element list of an element:

```
(define three-elt
  (λ e
    ((cons e)
     ((cons e)
      ((cons e)
       nil)))))
```

```
> (three-elt 1)
#<λ>
> (car (three-elt 1))
1
> (cdr (cdr (cdr (three-elt 1))))
{nil}: (λ l true)
```

(There is some special, flaky, magic which will let it print the names of things which have been `define`d as in the last case.)

Given definitions of `zero`, `zero?`, `succ` and `pred` (successor and predecessor), and a conditional function, `cond`, which looks like `(((cond test) if-true) if-false)`, you can then write a dirty version of `nth`:

```
(define nth
  (λ n (λ c
         (((cond (zero? n))
           (car c))
          ((nth (pred n)) (cdr c))))))
```

This is dirty because it uses `nth` free, but you can fix that with a combinator: I like U, so:

```
(define U
  ;; The U combinator
  (λ f (f f)))

(define nth
  (U (λ t
       (λ n
         (λ c
           (((cond (zero? n))
             (car c))
            (((U t) (pred n)) (cdr c))))))))
```

With either of these:

```
> ((nth (succ zero)) ((cons true) ((cons false) nil)))
{false}: (λ x (λ y y))
> ((nth zero) ((cons true) ((cons false) nil)))
{true}: (λ x (λ y x))
```

What I don't think you can do is implement `list` as such, because even if you added special magic to express nospread functions like `list` you then already need to have turned all its arguments into a list.  But I might be wrong about that.

All of the above functions exist in `examples/lc.rkt` in oa.

Comment: that is really cool, thanks for sharing! I'll take a look at the language later today (and hopefully I can understand a bit). So just a couple questions based on this: (1) the concept of a c-like array doesn't exist in lambda calc, unless you hardcode the size of it like you did with `three-elt` (or use a 'tricky' such as recursion). (2) You mention it's a one-argument language but then how can it do something like this? `(define false (λ x (λ y y)))`. Does that mean everything is curried and the `λ y y` translates into something like (in scheme) `(define false (lambda (x) (lambda (y) y)))` ?

Comment: ...and it would be called as something like: `((false 1) 2)` --> `2` ?

Comment: @David542: Well, the *only* kind of object the language can reason about is a single-argument function, so anything and everything else needs to be made of these.  (Because it uses the Racket reader you can *read* lots of other sorts of thing of course.)  And yes, everything is curried: λ leaves out the parens around the argument to make it look a bit more like 'λx.λy.y` for instance.  If you use the 'fancy' language then the currying and uncurrying is done for you so you could write `((λ (x y) y) a b)` say, which is really `(((λ x (λ y y)) a) b)`.

Comment: and what about the array concept? (part 1)?

Comment: Thanks for including your oa snippets. I'm familiar with how to encode conses as lambdas, but curiously nobody ever bothers to explain how to implement `nil` and `null?`. The solution is cute.

Comment: @David542: there are only single-argiment functions, but that is enough to simulate any other data structure at all.  There would be a worse-than-constant-factor slowdown.

Comment: @tfb I see, by the way, this may be related since you seem to be pretty good at this stuff! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67594976/example-assembly-machine-instruction-from-lambda-calculus